# Get parts of string separated by delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, substring

I have list of strings like

```
FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2-2-0-0-A4
FDENR7932ROR-1-0-0-A2 
FDENS3311-4-5-105-A2
FDENS1759-T-6-1-107-A3
```

The output needed to be created as,

```
FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2, 2, 0 , 0, A4
FDENR7932ROR, 1, 0, 0, A2 
FDENS3311, 4, 5, 105, A2
FDENS1759-T, 6, 1, 107, A3
```

The difficulty is, I need to check for `-`(hyphen) from End of the string and only last four strings are needed to be separated. Remained text can be used as is.

I tried:

```
string s = "FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2-2-0-0-A4";
int idx = s.LastIndexOf('-');
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, idx)); //FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2-2-0-0
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(idx + 1)); //A4
```

But it's for once, what about other three strings. :(

How to do it?

Comment: Use the `split` function and iterate through each part in the resulting array

Comment: I want `FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2` this string; `split` will destroy that into `FDENR8027ROR 0.10`, `CTW`, `SI2` !

Comment: If it's always the same amount of characters in the first bit, remove those first and only work on the last part :)

Comment: Naah Buddy, That's d only case, it may or may not have, but it surely has **last four hyphens**

Comment: You can `Split` by `-` but then concatenate first 3 items to a single string. Or get last 4 and concatenate the others into one.

Comment: @RomanKoliada, look my other examples, post edited

Comment: @Vikrant See my or Zohar Peled answer: it should work for all your cases.

Comment: @Vikrant https://dotnetfiddle.net/lbWYVd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
string s = "FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2-2-0-0-A4";
string[] parts = s.Split('-');
List<string> result = new List<string>{ string.Join("-", parts.Take(parts.Length - 4)) };
result.AddRange(parts.Skip(parts.Length - 4).Take(4));
```

See my working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lbWYVd).

Comment: I applied this code in `for` loop iterating through the list. Worked as desired

Answer (score 2):

Here is one fairly simple way to do it:

```
var str = "FDENR8027ROR 0.10-CTW-SI2-2-0-0-A4";
var arr = str.Split('-');
var result = new string[] {
    string.Join("-", arr.Take(arr.Length-4).ToArray()),
    arr[arr.Length-4],
    arr[arr.Length-3],
    arr[arr.Length-2],
    arr[arr.Length-1]
};
```

Comment: your answer is working, +1 for it, but I have a list of such strings. and Need to apply query on it. So, how can I do it on the fly :(